# localStorge ternary expression not working (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I'm trying to do this.

```
const isUserConnected = localStorage.getItem('token')

{isUserConnected.length ? null : 
      <div className='registerLogin'>
     Register...
      </div>
}
```

The ternary isn't acting in accordance to the localStorage content.

What is wrong?

Comment: What's the content of "isUserConnected"?

Comment: the content is a string

Comment: I mean make sure there's content coming from `localStorage.getItem`. Try a `console.log` and see if it's returning anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isUserConnected` is probably `undefined`.

In which case your code should look more like

```js
const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
const isUserConnected = token && token.length

{isUserConnected &&
  <div className='registerLogin'>
    Register...
  </div>
}
```